# Laravel route returns localhost despite I changed the env variable

Tags: laravel, routes

I have APP_URL env variable set to domainname.com and I have url set to the same domain in config file as well. route('route.name') in artisan tinker returns the proper domain. yet when used in the applicaiton code, it returns localhost. Any thoughts from you would be appreciated.

Edit: My environment is Github codespaces

Comment: clear cache and see

```php artisan cache:clear```

```php artisan route:clear```

Comment: Run php artisan optimize:clear and test again

Comment: `APP_URL` is only used by the CLI, it doesn't do anything for the 'web' as the host is what the web server is saying

Answer (score 2):

1. Try running ***php artisan optimize:clear*** command to clear cache,
   routes etc all in one go.
2. If you have separate frontend then change it there as well to hit the
   right backend with your provided domain name.
3. Restart your docker containers if you are using Docker.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a localhost issue with Codespaces and Laravel/Sail.

I think it's because Sail is running in a docker container, and Codespaces is running a proxy of the localhost of the docker your application isn't able to detect what the public address of your Codespaces instance is running from.

Turns out you need to trust the Codespaces proxy.

Edit TrustProxies.php and change the $proxies line to this:

```
protected $proxies = '*';
```

This instantly resolved my http://localhost/ problem. Laravel now routes to the proper https://*-80.app.github.dev/ address.

Comment: you saved my life. several days seeking for this. I was looking for an answer in linux devOps, but the answer was here.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you access the site in the browser through the actual domainname you set up, and not the localhost.

As lagbox said above: `APP_URL` is only used by the CLI, it doesn't do anything for the 'web' as the host is what the web server is saying"